# getClient not present in @kadena/client

Tags: pact, wallet-connect, kadena

I tried following the kadena [wallet connect example](https://github.com/kadena-io/wallet-connect-example)

However it can't import `{getClient}` from `'@kadena/client'`
This causes a failure when trying to get balances for the accounts

Comment: can you include the failure message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getClient` has been renamed to `createClient`. It can be used like this:

```
import { createClient } from '@kadena/client';

const { local } = createClient();

await local(tx);
```